# Word for object that is being spied on?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I was writing for school recently and came across the need for an object that is being spied ***on.*** The word's usage would be like this:

> As the spy lurked in the shadows he saw the _____ banging a wrench on the newly made machine.

I believe it will most likely be similar to mentor–mentee or the likes. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: A spy spies on an *enemy*!

Comment: http://www.rogerpbrown.com/spy/fs018.html suggests 'beta' (lingo), but I like 'target'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the object of surveillance is called the target, as in this web article: http://betanews.com/2015/11/10/the-next-target-for-surveillance-the-dark-web/.

I appreciate it's probably not as specific as you were looking for, but I couldn't find anything more suitable. I think it works perfectly well in your example sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JonLarby's more usual *target*, wouldn't *suspect* or *subject* fit the bill, particularly if it was important that you asked about the *object* being spied on, rather than the *person*, *henchman* or who have you.